# Import Adobe Illustrator AI files to vector format structure

Tags: c++, import, vector-graphics, file-format, adobe-illustrator

first of all: I do not want to implement AI import functionality based on AI file format specification for my own. Second: Adobe Illustrator is not installed on my target system, so I can not use it's programming interface.

But I want to import AI files into some CAD-like application to access the vector data out of this file afterwards (can be any kind of data structure, converting it to my own format is not a problem). How can this be done? Is there a library or something like this available which provides related functionality?

Thanks!